# Multiple MySQL access blocked using PHP but not MySQL locked

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a upload location so users can update a portion of my database with an uploaded file. The files are often up to 9gb, so inserting the 150,000,000 lines can take a few minutes.

After clicking the button on the website to update the database, PHP (using mysqli) basically goes on mysql lock down. If I open other tabs, they get nothing until the large update is complete. 
However, I know it's not actually locking the database/table, because from CLI i can still "SELECT count(*) FROM table" and it gives me a result right away.

What would be the best method of inserting 150,000,000 records while still letting other php pages access the db (for reading only)?

Comment: Sounds like the number of Apache workers is maxed out, and so it's hanging on to the request until there is a free worker?

Comment: Move it to a cronjob..

Comment: It's not simply Apache workers maxing out. Making another page that is just <?php echo 'Test' ?> opened immediately. It's only having problems on pages accessing the database. PHP works fine when the query runs, MySQL runs fine when the query runs. The issue appears to be related to MySQL + PHP combo. according to phpinfo() , mysqli.max_links is set to unlimited. I can't seem to figure out what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "INSERT DELAYED". The DELAYED option for the INSERT statement is a MySQL extension to standard SQL that is very useful if you have clients that cannot or need not wait for the INSERT to complete. This is a common situation when you use MySQL for logging and you also periodically run SELECT and UPDATE statements that take a long time to complete.

You can read about this resource on the official documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html).

;-)

Comment: This sounds logical, but doesn't seem to help. I think I'm having more of a PHP block than a MySQL block. I can already access MySQL just fine from things other than PHP. Is there a php or mysqli restriction on how many things can access the db at once?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with sessions.

Since the upload validated against the login in the session, and I failed to session_write_close() before starting the db writes the session file remained locked for the entire 9gb read/write to the db.

This explains why I could still use CLI mysql, and basic php (the basic php I was using to test had no sessions in it).